# Alternative for checking if cells change in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there another way of finding if cells change in a worksheet other than the following?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
 If Target.Address=$A$1 Then
    'something
 End If
End Sub
```

What I'm particularly interested in is if there's a way of checking without `Target` in the brackets at the beginning, as in, I would need a code with the `Private Sub() End Sub` structure (nothing in the brackets is required for my code because I want to make a button with this function).

Comment: "if there's a way of checking without declaring Target in the brackets at the beginning" - you don't declare it, it's part of the information you receive. What other way would you need?

Comment: @MátéJuhász i would need to have a 'Private Sub() End Sub' code. it is required to have nothing in the brackets at the beginning

Comment: why would you need to have that? it seems to be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MátéJuhász because i want to make a button that uses this function and buttons don't work if i put something in the brackets

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is triggered by an event, there is no way to call it from a macro. You can create a macro  which is called by your button, and you can also call the same macro from your `Worksheet_Change` Sub.

Comment: @MátéJuhász i understand. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104494/discussion-between-anne-and-mate-juhasz).